# How can I confirm if my application is running on Apache Spark cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have setup a Apache Spark master and workers. The workers are started and register themselves with the master which the master has acknowledged. When I submit a application using a following command

```
bin\spark-submit.cmd --class com.sample.spark.MySparkApplication --master spark://172.31.22.172:7077 --deploy-mode=cluster C:\\apachespark\\lib\\MySparkApplication.jar
```

This returns the results but I am not sure if the processing happened on the workers or was it just the master that processed the problem? How can I confirm if the workers participated in the processing?

I checked the Spark master UI at http://localhost:8080. It lists the workers registered with the master but under Running and Completed application it shows 0 even though I have run the `sparksubmit` command multiple times with successful run of the application.

I realized I need to specify the deploy-mode as cluster. When I run the above `sparksubmit` command along with the deploy-mode-cluster it throws an exception Exception from cluster was: `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Here is the log and the exception dump

> Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
>   Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
>   15/08/25 16:25:20 INFO RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://172.31.22.98:7077.
>   15/08/25 16:25:20 WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark://172.31.22.172:7077.
>
> Warning: Master endpoint spark://172.31.22.98:7077 was not a REST server. Falling back to legacy submission gateway instead.
>
> 15/08/25 16:25:20 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>    where applicable
>
> Driver successfully submitted as driver-20150825162522-0001
>
> ... waiting before polling master for driver state
>
> ... polling master for driver state
>
> State of driver-20150825162522-0001 is ERROR
>
> Exception from cluster was: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apachespark\lib\spark-application.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
>
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apachespark\lib\spark-application.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.spark-project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:124)
>           at org.spark-project.guava.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:114)
>           at org.spark-project.guava.io.ByteSource.copyTo(ByteSource.java:202)
>           at org.spark-project.guava.io.Files.copy(Files.java:436)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$copyRecursive(Utils.scala:598)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.copyFile(Utils.scala:569)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:646)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:453)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$DriverRunner$$downloadUserJar(DriverRun
>   ner.scala:150)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverRunner$$anon$1.run(DriverRunner.scala:79)*

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to add the ̀`spark-application.jar` while submitting the app.

Comment: One thing I don't understand here is why submit to 189.31.77.133 which is unlikely to be your localhost but check Web UI on a local machine.

Comment: @eliasah I am specifying the jar file as part of the spark-submit command. Here is the command i fire.  _bin\spark-submit.cmd --class com.sample.spark.MySparkApplication --master spark://172.31.22.172:7077 --deploy-mode=cluster C:\\apachespark\\lib\\MySparkApplication.jar_

Comment: There shouldn't be an equal sign between --deploy-mode and cluster. The spark-submit command will drop this option thus is might not be running on cluster indeed.

Comment: check the address of your master from ui , then check whether you provided the master url correctly in SparkConf .

Comment: if you run spark app by net-beans or eclipse you can only see the results in the output of the IDE only and the 8080 will not show any things.